# MS SQL SERVER LAG

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, lead

[image]

I'm trying to apply a condition to `LAG` in a SQL query. Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the query:

```
  SELECT CONCAT([FirstName],' ',[LastName]) AS employee,
         CAST([ArrivalTime] AS DATE) AS date,
         CAST(DATEADD(hour,2,FORMAT([ArrivalTime],'HH:mm')) AS TIME) as time,
         CASE [EventType]
         WHEN 20001 THEN 'ENTRY'
         ELSE 'EXIT'
         END AS Action,
         OutTime = 
  CASE [EventType]
  WHEN '20001'
  THEN DATEDIFF(minute,Lag([ArrivalTime],1) OVER(ORDER BY [CardHolderID], [ArrivalTime]), [ArrivalTime]) 
  ELSE
  NULL
  END
  FROM [CCFTEvent].[dbo].[ReportEvent]
  LEFT JOIN [CCFTCentral].[dbo].[Cardholder] ON  [CCFTEvent].[dbo].[ReportEvent].[CardholderID] = [CCFTCentral].[dbo].[Cardholder].[FTItemID]
  WHERE EventClass = 41
  AND [FirstName] IS NOT NULL
  AND [FirstName] LIKE 'Leeann%'
```

The problem I have is when the times are subtracted between two different dates, it must also be `NULL` when subtracting between two different dates.

[image]

The 910 is incorrect.

Comment: Both of your images look like query results.  It would be more helpful if you showed your source data.

Comment: You don't need both `[FirstName] IS NOT NULL` and `[FirstName] LIKE 'Leeann%'`. If `FirstName` is `LIKE 'Leeann%'`, then it would automatically be `NOT NULL`. Also, you should indicate which tables the variables are coming from. If `FirstName` is coming from `Cardholder`, then you may as well move the condition to the `JOIN` and change it to an `INNER JOIN`. Plus placing variables will help future you better understand the flow of the query.

Comment: What is your input and what do you expect the final output to be? Both of your images show the same thing. I'm assuming `ArrivalTime` is a `datetime` datatype?  And what version of SQL Server?

Comment: And what makes 910 incorrect? Is 917 also incorrect?

Comment: Thanks you for the response. The 910 is incorrect because it is calculating between two different dates, when this happens then I want it to be NULL. I am trying to calculate the total time an employee is not in the building.

Comment: 917 is also incorrect because its between two different dates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add another condition to your `case` statement. i.e.

```
...
CASE 
   WHEN [EventType] = '20001' AND DATEDIFF(DAY,[ArrivalTime],LAG([ArrivalTime]) over (ORDER BY [CardHolderID], [ArrivalTime])) > 0
   THEN NULL
   WHEN [EventType] = '20001'
   THEN DATEDIFF(minute,Lag([ArrivalTime],1) OVER(ORDER BY [CardHolderID], [ArrivalTime]), [ArrivalTime])
   ELSE NULL
```

Comment: Will give this a try. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the LAG just needs to be partitioned by the date (& some other fields for good measure).

If the previous date is in another partition,
  then the LAG will return NULL,
    then the datediff will return NULL.

```
SELECT 
 CONCAT(holder.FirstName+' ', holder.LastName) AS employee,
 CAST(repev.ArrivalTime AS DATE) AS [date],
 CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(repev.ArrivalTime,'+02:00') AS TIME)  as [time],
 IIF(repev.EventType = 20001, 'ENTRY', 'EXIT') AS Action,
 (CASE WHEN repev.EventType = 20001
  THEN DATEDIFF(minute, LAG(repev.ArrivalTime) 
                        OVER (PARTITION BY repev.EventClass, repev.CardholderID, CAST(repev.ArrivalTime AS DATE) 
                              ORDER BY repev.ArrivalTime), repev.ArrivalTime)
  END) AS OutTime
FROM [CCFTEvent].[dbo].[ReportEvent] AS repev
LEFT JOIN [CCFTCentral].[dbo].[Cardholder] AS holder ON holder.FTItemID = repev.CardholderID
WHERE repev.EventClass = 41
  AND holder.FirstName LIKE 'Leeann%'
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be3580618ebacd6e27d853bb8259502d)*

Comment: Let me try this out, I haven't used partioning yet. Thank you for the response!